# Concatenate strings in ocaml with newline between them

Tags: ocaml

I'd like to do something like this

```
String.concat '\n' [str1; str2 ... strn]
```

so I can print in a file. But ocaml doesn't allow me to do that. What can I do?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
String.concat "\n" [str1; str2 ... strn]
```

works fine. The problem is that you used `'\n'`, which is a character literal, not a string. Example:

```
# String.concat '\n' ["abc"; "123"];;
Error: This expression has type char but an expression was expected of type
     string
# String.concat "\n" ["abc"; "123"];;
- : string = "abc\n123"
```

Comment: How would you have `String.concat` print "abc" and "123" on two different lines`?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Jane Street's base module for your standard library you'll have to do it like so:

```ml
# #require "base";;
# open! Base;;
# String.concat ~sep:"\n" ["abc"; "123"];;
- : string = "abc\n123"
```

Jane Street really likes to take advantage of named arguments.